# IE11 triggers css transition on page load when non-applied media query exists

Tags: css, media-queries, css-transitions, internet-explorer-11

I have a situation which only occurs on IE11.  Chrome, Firefox, Safari (tablet and phone) all work as expected.  I have created a transition for a panel(DIV) that slides in/out from the side.  On pageload it should NOT "animate" but snap into the appropriate position.  But on IE11 when the page loads the transition is "played" ONLY if there is a media query involved with that element matching the highest level of CSS specificity for the selector.  The strange thing is that the **media query is not even appropriate (should never be applied when the page is loaded in my test)**.

The following simple code duplicates my issue:

## CSS

```
.standard {
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width:50px;  height:50px;  border:1px solid black;  background-color:green;   margin:3em;
}

button + .standard {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

button.on + .standard {
  transform:rotate(0deg);
}

/* REMOVE THE FOLLOWING COMMENTS to see issue on page load using IE11 - make sure window is larger than 800 pixels */
/*
@media only screen and (max-width:800px) {
  button.on + .standard {
    background-color:red;
    transform:rotate(270deg);
  }
}
*/
```

## HTML

```
<button class="on" onclick="this.classList.toggle('on');">Rotate Test</button>
<div class="standard">&nbsp;</div>
```

So if size of the browser window is greater than 800 pixels the media query should not be applied.  However, IE11 seems to act like it applies the media query and then reverts back to the non-media query CSS which actually triggers the transition.  If the media query content selector does not match the highest level of CSS specificity as defined outside the media query, the transition will not be observed on page load (in other words if my media query CSS selector was less specific [say `button + .standard`], you would not see the transition "played").

Any ideas how to prevent this transition from "playing" on page load using IE11 without having to write javascript?

Answer (score 18):

Worked with MicroSoft support and logged a bug.  There is a workaround for this issue.

Instead of using the media query

```
@media only screen and (max-width:800px)
```

change the query to be the following:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:1px) and (max-width:800px)
```

This should not be required (it should be implied) but placing the min-width in the query resolves the "PLAYING" of transition on page load.  MS should fix it but since there is a workaround, the likelihood of a quick turnout is low.

Comment: Can you link to the bug you submitted with MS? I have a similar issue.

Comment: This works partially for my case - if the window is larger than 800px then the issue is fixed since it won't load any media queries. However if the window is say 500px, we need the media query to be loaded in this case, which it doesn't, even with the fix in place.

Comment: I had similar issue but my media query used min-width:768px. adding max-width:4000px didn't help but moving my STYLE tag below the HTML fixed everything

Comment: Bless you for this fix holy shit, I debugged everything for hours and now it's working... Damn IE

Answer (score 1):

Not a completely javascript free solution but you can add a class to the entire page on the body tag:

```
body.pageload * {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    -moz-transition: none !important;
    -ms-transition: none !important;
    -o-transition: none !important;
}
```

and remove that class after the page has loaded

```
$("window").load(function() {
    $("body").removeClass("pageload");
});
```

Comment: Yes, this was what i was trying to avoid

Answer (score 0):

The answer of user3546826 works when the window is larger than the defined `max-width`. When the window is smaller than the transition is still animated by IE / Edge. This can be avoided with the following workaround (just an example):

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: 240px;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  top:50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    left: 0; /* define left here for IE / Edge */
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    left: -240px;
  }
}
```