# CSS query and transition are not working correctly in IE and Edge

Tags: css, media-queries, transition

I have a div with some styles and a fixed width for big screens :

```
.div {
    width: 1600px;
    transition: width 0.5s
}
```

And I am using media query with smaller fixed width for smaller screens :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .div {
        width: 400px;
    }
}
```

My problem is when I enter to the website (not refresh), if the browser width is bigger than 1000px, the animation will fire up (the div get from 400px to 1600px) !

I tried to add the *transition* to the media query, but the transition will not work when I resize the browser (less than 400px to over 400px) which is normal.

I can't understand why the browser use styles inside the media query when it doesn't match the browser with !

Please check this URL with a very basic example :

https://octamerous-hunts.000webhostapp.com/

**Update**
I just tested in Mozilla and Chrome and it work without problem, actually the problem occur only when I use IE and Edge !

The code :

```
<head>

    <style>

        .div1 {
            position: relative;
            width: 1400px;
            height: 200px;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -700px;
            background-color: royalblue;
            transition: width 0.5s, margin-left 0.5s;
        }


        @media only screen and (max-width: 1399px) {
            .div1 {
                width: 1000px;
                margin-left: -500px;
            }
        }

    </style>

</head>


<body>

    <div class="div1">



    </div>

</body>
```

**Update 2**

I found a similar question :

[IE/Edge - CSS3 transitions firing on navigate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39276551/ie-edge-css3-transitions-firing-on-navigate)

But the solution provided doesn't work !

**Update 3**

I found the solution :

[IE11 triggers css transition on page load when non-applied media query exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673707/ie11-triggers-css-transition-on-page-load-when-non-applied-media-query-exists)

That fix the problem with IE and Edge !

Comment: What do you mean when you enter the website(not refresh)? Going to the website and a refresh is essentially the same thing as far as your css is concerned. You are loading the page in both cases

Comment: Please provide the HTML and CSS required to reproduce your problem, preferably in a Stack Snippet.

Comment: @Huangism well, I am agree with you, but when I refresh the page, everything is fine, when I enter the URL in a blank page and press enter, I will have this problem :S

Comment: You will need to provide a url then, currently, there is no way for us to reproduce this

Comment: @Huangism No. He must supply a complete representation here within the question, not a URI. That will only get this question closed. [mcve]

Comment: @Rob I already tried his scenario in a fiddle, I don't think this issue (if it is an issue) is reproducible using a code snippet

Comment: @Huangism Then he's out of luck.

Comment: Then he can provide a snippet and an url

Comment: as per your media query, your animation will work when you resize at 1000px not at 400px.

Comment: @Zuber with the current provided code, the transition will occur resizing from big to small and small to big

Comment: I try to add a URL with the code or an example at least (I am working on local and I don't have online URL and will not post all the codes online yet)

Comment: @Soheyl you don't need post all the code, just post simplified example. Just post the `.div` with its related styles. the transition shouldn't occur when loading the page

Comment: @HiddenHobbes I added a very basic example

Comment: @Huangism I added a very basic example

Comment: @Soheyl add the code to the question and vote for reopen. I opened your url in FF and chrome, no transition on load. What browser are you seeing this issue on?

Comment: @Huangism IE and Edge, not tested in this browsers :S my bad, I will try now, How can I vote for reopening the question ?